# Simple binding questions

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

I am trying a simple application which is like this-

**View:**

1. A table view showing count of entity 1 in first column and count of entity 2 in second column. Here each row specifies count of different entities at a particular date.
2. A text field showing- total count of entity 1 multiplied by 35.
3. A text field showing- sum of count of entities in both the columns.

eg.

(entity1) (entity2)

<2> <3>

<4> <2>

<5> <7>

> requirement 1: text field specified in
>   pt. 2 should show - 385 ie. (11 * 35)
>
> requirement 2: text field specified in
>   pt. 3 should show - 23 ie. (11 + 12)

**Model:**

An object with two properties:

int entity1Count

int entity2Count

I am using an array controller object to show data in table view.

My question is -

> Can I implement my requirements via
>   bindings in IB? If yes then how?

Thanks,

Miraaj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to implement requirement 1, via bindings in IB using NSNumberFormatter and its multiplier property :)

but I am still unable to implement requirement 2 :(

Any suggestion ?

Thanks,

Miraaj